# ggplot2: Why stript.text.y not inheriting 'angle' from strip.text when complete theme?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I want to set the angle of facet labels for vertical axis and I noticed that I have to use set `strip.text.y` in the theme specifically as it does not seem to inherit if I set the angle at the level of its parent, `strip.text`, even if `complete=TRUE`.

Why is that?  (Perhaps I'm using an incomplete theme without realizing it?) Using ggplot2 v3.3.3.

The following attempts to set `angle=45` doesn't change the default angle rendering.

```
(p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(rows = vars(Species)))

p + theme(strip.text   = element_text(angle=45))
p + theme(strip.text   = element_text(angle=45), complete=TRUE) #Results in heavier font.
```

[image: Incomplete theme] [image: Complete theme]
Why didn't `complete=TRUE` trigger inheritance?

Had to be specific:

```
p + theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle=45)) # Works!
```

[image]

I read the section titled "Complete vs Incomplete (themes)" in the vignette below but that wasn't clear on this issue.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hierarchy for theme elements:

- `strip.text` inherits from `text`
- `strip.text.y` inherits from `strip.text`
- `strip.text.y.left` (and right) inherits from `strip.text.y`.

'Inheritance' in the theme's case means that a child's properties get filled in by the parent's properties, when this property is missing in the child.

If you evaluate `theme_get()$strip.text.y` with the default theme, you'll see that `angle` is `-90`: not missing. So whenever you set something in the parent `strip.text`, the `strip.text.y`'s angle overrules the parents angle. I think Kara Woo discussed this behaviour in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izV-qK3nlhA).

As a sidenote, I don't think you *ever* need to specify `complete` for normal plotting purposes. It might only be a useful argument for building new themes for a package or something.

Comment: I see that `theme_get()$strip.text` evaluates to NULL.  So what you're saying is that by default the parent's angle is NULL and the child's angle is not null.  Therefore, setting a value for the parent has no effect on the child, which already had a specific value of the property.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep that logic seems right to me.